# Oracle and vnext ASP.NET 5

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, odac

Is the Oracle Data Provider ODAC compatible with ASP.NET 5 (vnext)?  All of the documentation I found shows compatibility up to ASP.NET 4.6.

Comment: I doubt it's related to ASP.NET, but instead .NET. In which case it should work with .NET 4.6, but not .NET Core.